# protractor: how can I fix UnknownError: javascript error: angular is not defined?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am using this code sample to call angular from my protractor test:
https://github.com/andresdominguez/protractor-meetup

When I run the member3-spec I get an error:

```
2) Member should update existing member
   Message:
     UnknownError: javascript error: angular is not defined
JavaScript stack:
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

This spec calls a function in a helper called api-helper.js:

```
module.exports = {
  member: {
    findAll: function() {
      return browser.executeAsyncScript(function(callback) {
        var api = angular.injector(['ProtractorMeetupApp']).get('apiService');
        api.member.query({}, function(data) {
          callback(data);
        });
      })
    },
    create: function(data) {

      return browser.executeAsyncScript(function(data, callback) {
          console.log('inside asyncscript call');
        var api = angular.injector(['ProtractorMeetupApp']).get('apiService');
        api.member.save(data, function(newItem) {
          callback(newItem._id);
        })
      }, data);
    }
  }
};
```

When I debug this the executeAsyncScript call returns with this error see above.
What am I missing in this sample?

Comment: Where and how? Could you show a code sample?